I can't see table details with \d
These are my tables. I'm trying to see the details of Products table.
demo6pa=# d
List of relations
Schema |      Name       |   Type   |  Owner  
--------+-----------------+----------+----------
public | Products        | table    | postgres
public | Products_id_seq | sequence | postgres
public | SequelizeMeta   | table    | postgres
public | Services        | table    | postgres
public | Services_id_seq | sequence | postgres
public | Users           | table    | postgres
public | Users_id_seq    | sequence | postgres
(7 rows)

demo6pa=# d Products
Did not find any relation named "Products".

I expected to see the details of Product tables, although I'm getting "Did not find any relation named Products"

Nevermind, I got it, I just need to use double quotes like this
\d "Products"


That's why you should never use upper case in the database object names. You will keep running into problems forever. Advice: Fix the names as soon as possible
